# Call UICollectionViewCell content outside class

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

so I wanted to ask how it is possible to add function to a CollectionViewCell which I can use in my main ViewController.

For example:
I have a CollectionViewCell file with a label

```
class myCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

func hideLabel() {
myLabel.hidden = true
   }

}
```

And I want to call this function in my ViewController.
How do I this or do I add this function somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call this function with the `UICollection
ViewCell` instance.

create and instance of your `uicollectionviewcell` like :

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellNibName", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell 
and call function like :
cell.hideLabel()
```

Although you can hide label like :

```
cell.myLabel.hidden = true
```